Solving $\max |c^Tx+d|$ such that $c_i(x) = 0\;\forall i = \mathcal{E}$, and $c_i(x) \geq 0\;\forall i \in \mathcal{I}$
I want to solve $\max |c^Tx+d|$ such that $c_i(x) = 0\;\forall i = \mathcal{E}$, and $c_i(x) \geq 0\;\forall i \in \mathcal{I}$.
My idea is to split the absolute value. So, on the one hand, solve
$$\max c^Tx +d \quad\text{such that}\quad c_i(x) = 0\;\forall i = \mathcal{E}, c_i(x) \geq 0\;\forall i \in \mathcal{I} \tag1$$
and then solve
$$\min c^Tx+d \quad\text{such that}\quad c_i(x) = 0\;\forall i = \mathcal{E}, c_i(x) \geq 0\;\forall i \in \mathcal{I} \tag2$$
and in the end take the maximum in absolute value.
But I am unsure, if this approach is correct or if I am missing some edge cases.

Yes, this is correct.  In case it makes the problem easier, you could optionally impose lower bound $c^T x + d \ge 0$ when you maximize and upper bound $c^T x + d \le 0$ when you minimize.

Thank you for the answer. Just to be sure, I do not need to impose the bounds right= I can also ignore them?

Those bounds are optional but might help solve faster.

Thanks you very much!
